# How to create semicircle from sharp edge

Tags: modeling, edges

[image]

I need create from these edges semicircle. What can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean how can you bow out a subdivided plane into half of a tube?

Comment: It is a block and I need subdivide these 4 edges

Comment: You mean bevel?

Comment: yes, sorry for my english.... is so poor

Comment: Select the edges, then hit ctrl-b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to cut a hole in the shape of a semicircle, you can do it easily by erasing the two faces and adding a *Subsurface* modifier.

Then add two control edgeloops on the sides you want to be flat.

[image: Semi Circle Subsurf]

Alternatively, if want a drawn shape instead of a hole, just select one of the radial vertices and use the *Spin* modifier. The current position of the *3D Cursor* will be used as the center.
Adjust settings like angle and number of segments as desired.

[image: Semicircle Spin]

Answer (score 0):

Enable LoopTools addon in Preferences, choose the lines you want to convert to semi-circle, next look for "LoopTools" found on the Tools tab, then use the 'Circle' widget (found under 'Bridge') and adjust parameters accordingly. Optionally, you could use the "To Sphere" tool (Shift+Alt+S), but it's more  'automatic' and not as configurable.